# How to load resource bundle from file, not from jar, same bundle base name

Tags: java, resourcebundle, urlclassloader

There are resource bundles with the same base name in both file system and jar. 
Try to load the resource bundle from file system, not from jar.

```
URLClassLoader urlLoader = new URLClassLoader(new java.net.URL[]{filePathURL});
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle( "my.bundle", locale, urlLoader );
```

The bundle is loaded from jar, not from the file system. Why?
If I changed the bundle base name to my.foo.bundle(different from the bundle name in jar), it worked. But the bundle names are the same for file system and in jar. Is there a way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that it is because of the way URLClassLoader loads resources.

**In case of URLClassLoader:**
Whenever a resource is requested, it first asks the parent class-loader to load it. If that resource is not available it then checks the child class loaders.

**Not sure whether this is the best way but, possible solutions:**

**1.** Use the constructor

```
`public URLClassLoader(URL[] urls, ClassLoader parent)`
```

And give null for parent

*Like so:*

```
URLClassLoader urlLoader = new URLClassLoader(new java.net.URL[]{filePathURL}, null);
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle( "my.bundle", locale, urlLoader );
```

**2.** Extend the URLClassLoader and override the method `getResource` method to load from your class loader first:

```
public URL getResource(String name) {
    URL url = findResource(name); // this will load from your class loader
    if (url == null) {
        if (parent != null) {
            url = parent.getResource(name);
        } else {
            url = getBootstrapResource(name);
        }
    }

    return url;
}
```